# Using Ansible variables in testinfra

Tags: python, testing, ansible, pytest, testinfra

Using TestInfra with Ansible backend for testing purposes. Everything goes fine except using Ansible itself while running tests

test.py

```
import pytest
def test_zabbix_agent_package(host):
    package = host.package("zabbix-agent")
    assert package.is_installed
    package_version = host.ansible("debug", "msg={{ zabbix_agent_version }}")["msg"]
    (...)
```

where zabbix_agent_version is an Ansible variable from group_vars. It can be obtained by running this playbook

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: debug
    debug: msg={{ zabbix_agent_version }}
```

command executing tests

```
pytest --connection=ansible --ansible-inventory=inventory  --hosts=$hosts -v test.py
```

ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
timeout = 10
host_key_checking = False
library=library/
retry_files_enabled = False
roles_path=roles/
pipelining=true
ConnectTimeout=60
remote_user=deploy
private_key_file=/opt/jenkins/.ssh/deploy
```

the output I get is

```
self = <ansible>, module_name = 'debug', module_args = 'msg={{ zabbix_agent_version }}', check = True, kwargs = {}
result = {'failed': True, 'msg': "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'zabbix_agent_version' is undefined"}

    def __call__(self, module_name, module_args=None, check=True, **kwargs):
        if not self._host.backend.HAS_RUN_ANSIBLE:
            raise RuntimeError((
                "Ansible module is only available with ansible "
                "connection backend"))
        result = self._host.backend.run_ansible(
            module_name, module_args, check=check, **kwargs)
        if result.get("failed", False) is True:
>           raise AnsibleException(result)
E           AnsibleException: Unexpected error: {'failed': True,
E            'msg': u"the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'zabbix_agent_version' is undefined"}

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/testinfra/modules/ansible.py:70: AnsibleException
```

Any idea why Ansible can't see this variable when running testinfra's Ansible module while it can see it while running Ansible alone?

Comment: Ansible version 2.2.1.0
Python version 2.7.5
Testinfra version 1.6.4
Pytest version 3.1.3

Comment: Where is `zabbix_agent_version` defined when you're running Ansible manually? Is this coming from a custom fact on the remote host, or is this set in a local variable file?

Comment: zabbix_agent_version is defined in group_vars. when running a playbook that checks this fact (debug: msg={{ zabbix_agent_version }}) it can be obtained by Ansible.

Answer (score 6):

If `zabbix_agent_version` is a variable set using `group_vars`, then it seems as if you should be accessing it using `host.ansible.get_variables()` rather than running `debug` task. In any case, both should work.  If I have, in my current directory:

```
test_myvar.py
group_vars/
  all.yml
```

And in `group_vars/all.yml` I have:

```
myvar: value
```

And in `test_myvar.py` I have:

```
def test_myvar_using_get_variables(host):
    all_variables = host.ansible.get_variables()
    assert 'myvar' in all_variables
    assert all_variables['myvar'] == 'myvalue'


def test_myvar_using_debug_var(host):
    result = host.ansible("debug", "var=myvar")
    assert 'myvar' in result
    assert result['myvar'] == 'myvalue'


def test_myvar_using_debug_msg(host):
    result = host.ansible("debug", "msg={{ myvar }}")
    assert 'msg' in result
    assert result['msg'] == 'myvalue'
```

Then all tests pass:

```
$ py.test --connection=ansible --ansible-inventory=hosts -v 
test_myvar.py 
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.2.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /home/lars/env/common/bin/python2
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/testinfra, inifile:
plugins: testinfra-1.8.1.dev2
collected 3 items                                                               

test_myvar.py::test_myvar_using_get_variables[ansible://localhost] PASSED
test_myvar.py::test_myvar_using_debug_var[ansible://localhost] PASSED
test_myvar.py::test_myvar_using_debug_msg[ansible://localhost] PASSED

=========================== 3 passed in 1.77 seconds ===========================
```

Can you confirm that the layout of our files (in particular, the location of your `group_vars` directory relative to the your tests) matches what I've shown here?

Comment: Yes, I do have the same layout as the one that you presented. While doing further tests it is strange, that when I try to get some fact built-in by Ansible (like ansible_ssh_host) testinfra can find it without a problem, but when I try something that is being set up by my group_vars it can not find it although when running debug Ansible can see it.

Answer (score 4):

I chased an answer to this for days.  Here's what finally worked for me.  Essentially you are using testinfra's Ansible module to access the include_vars function of Ansible.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def AnsibleVars(host):
ansible_vars = host.ansible(
    "include_vars", "file=./group_vars/all/vars.yml")
return ansible_vars["ansible_facts"]
```

Then in my tests, I included the function as a parameter:

```
def test_something(host, AnsibleVars):
```

This solution was taken partially from https://github.com/metacloud/molecule/issues/151

I had an interesting issue where I was trying to include the variables from my main playbook and I was receiving an error of "must be stored as a dictionary/hash" when including the playbook.yml file.  Separating the variables out into the group_vars/all/vars.yml file resolved that error.